# Image of complex function $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find the image of $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ under the set $\{ z \in \Bbb C :   |z| < 1 \}$. I think it transforms the unitary circle in a half plane but i don't know how to show it. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Typically a good place to start is by rationalizing the denominator. Multiply the top and bottom by the conjugate of $z+1$ then simplify. This should make the image easier to identify.

Comment: There are many approaches, but you might consider writing $f$ as $f(z)=1-\frac{2}{z+1}$ and then recognizing that $f$ is a composition of elementary functions. Do you know anything about inversion $z\mapsto 1/z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\omega=\frac {z-1}{z+1}\implies z=\frac {1+\omega}{1-\omega}$

Now $\,\,|z|<1\implies |1+\omega|<|1-\omega|\implies Re(\omega)<0$

Comment: This only tells that the image is included in the half plane $x<0$, we still need to prove that all points can be reached.

Comment: All steps are reversible